# How to align multiple divs vertically on the left and one big div in the right?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying so hard to find a solution to this but I couldnt achieve the desired solution.

I want to have the following: [image]

and this is what I have tried so far:

```css
#outer-div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #027DB4;
}

#inner-div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="inner-div" class="input-group">
    <label>1</label>
    <select>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="inner-div" class="input-group">
    <label>2</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="inner-div" class="input-group">
    <label>3</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="inner-div" class="input-group">
    <label>4</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S. I don't want to use float because it ruins everything else in that page.**

Comment: That's invalid HTML - you can use IDs only once per document. Use classes instead.

Comment: I would recommend using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) Layout.

Comment: @Johannes it actually works in other cases where i am aligning some divs vertically in both sides

Comment: Then you are just lucky that your browser tolerates it. It's still invalid HTML, and other browsers might *not* tolerate it.

Comment: @ssssss It isn't semantic HTML to use an ID more than once. Targeting is hard to manage.

Comment: @TannerDolby I am really bad at this, grid seems very difficult to figure out

Comment: @Johannes I just tested with other divs, now it look very bad. ID actually works, but not Class. Strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use flexbox for this kind of stuff

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div {
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='left'>
    <div> one</div>
    <div> two</div>
    <div> three</div>
  </div>
  <div id='right'>
  <div>right</div>
  <div>another right</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I do overflow-y why doesnt it work for the right side? Try adding more divs vertically to the right side and you see it will keep expanding down, but overflow-y should have worked but it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

DCR is right on with flexbox. You can also use CSS grid and avoid nesting items https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout.

```css
#outer-div {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #027DB4;
    display: grid;
}

.right-column {
    grid-column: 2 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
    <div class="input-group">1</div>
    <div class="input-group">2</div>
    <div class="input-group">3</div>
    <div class="input-group right-column">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.box1{`
`display:flex;`
`justify-content: space-between;`
`}`

`<div class="box1">`
`<div class="box2">` 
`<div class="div1">1</div>`
`<div class="div2">2</div>`
`<div class="div3">3</div>`

`</div>`

```
  `<div class="div4">4</div>`
```

`</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to try CSS Grid, this is a route to try. `.right` and `.left` class properties are added to allow more targeted styling, if needed, and borders are added to the parent and container elements to highlight them.

```css
.outer-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.inner-div.left {
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inner-div.right {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div left">
    <label>1</label>
    <select>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div left">
    <label>2</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div left">
    <label>3</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div right">
    <label>4</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```